# FQDN UNC Path Prompts for creds, Shortname works

Tags: windows, unc

I have an environment where multiple cnames exist for a server.  I have the reg entry \LSA\DisableLoopbackCheck Enabled, which allows these cnames to work with UNC, but one of the cnames will only work with the shortname, ie \\hostname, but \\hostname.domain.local fails.  Was wondering if anyone had ever seen this.

Servers in question are Win2016

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to configure DisableStrictNameChecking.

Comment: well, we've tried that too, services\LANMANServer\params\DisableStrictNameChecking and \control\lsa\disableloopbackcheck are both enabled